# Click event doesn't fire for disabled text field?

Tags: jquery

I have a disabled text field that I want to become enabled when I click it. Unfortunately, it seems that the text field's `click()` event doesn't fire while it's disabled.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Would you like to post some code?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Unfortunately, disabling a control also disables its events (it's by design).

To work around that limitation, you could add a `<div>` absolutely positioned above the `<input>` field (higher `z-index`) and attach the `click()` event to that `<div>`. Once clicked, dispose of the `<div>` and enable your `<input>`.

If you just want to prevent the user from changing the value of the `<input>`, use `readonly` instead of `disabled`. This will not disable the event handlers.

```
$('#myInput').attr('readonly', true);
```