# Click on (disabled) input not getting triggered on Mozilla

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click on a disabled input on Chrome it's giving me the desired results but in Mozilla due to the disabled class, it isn't rendering anything. What do I do to make it work?

```
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".divclick").click(function(){
                alert("jsk");
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="divclick" height="100px" width="100px" style="background:red;">
        <input type="text" disabled>
    </div>
</body>
```

Ps: already tried putting a wrapper around it. I wish only the desired Input

Comment: just because its a different component and events are seperate

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100319/event-on-a-disabled-input

Comment: @acarlon thanks for that one but unfortunately my handler is not on a wrapper(div) its on the input itself. i dnt intend to use a wrap

Comment: @user1560148 you *have* to use a workaround, since firefox does not emit mouse events on disabled inputs. Chrome does the same for other types, e.g. `type="checkbox"`.

Answer (score 5):

I came across the this thread https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=218093.

```
Firefox, and perhaps other browsers, disable DOM events on form fields that are disabled. 
Any event that starts at the disabled form field is completely canceled and does not propagate up the DOM tree. 
Correct me if I'm wrong, but if you click on the disabled button, 
the source of the event is the disabled button and the click event is completely wiped out. 
The browser literally doesn't know the button got clicked, nor does it pass the click event on. 
It's as if you are clicking on a black hole on the web page.
```

Source is here [Click event doesn't fire for disabled text field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237047/click-event-doesnt-fire-for-disabled-text-field#answer-1237054)

Here is the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CX8WQ/3/)